# How to adjust the x labels on seasonal_decompose()

Tags: python

I'm trying to rotate and reduce the x label on seasonal_decompose(),

from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal. However, I only got the from the last chart to change. How can I edit all of them?

Please help me.

```
model_series = tsa.seasonal_decompose(y, model='additive')
fig = model_series.plot()
plt.xticks(fontsize=7)
# plt.show()
```

Comment: Which part of this code rotates and reduces the x labels of the last chart?

Comment: What does it mean to "reduce" a label? Do you mean "reduce the size"?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?